# When using "set New password" for customer Magento sends email with admin password reset link

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, email-templates, password-recovery

I am using Magento 1.8.1.0

When I use Password Management -> New password field in the Customers -> Manage Customers -> Account Information page for a single customer record the selected customer is sent an email with auto generated password using admin password reset email template, and all links in the above mentioned email point to domain.com/admin page. The password is changed, and user can log in from frontend using the password, both in cases where it is auto generated and set manually, but the link in the email is pure confusing.

This is clearly not the desired functionality. The template used in this case is /app/locale/en_US/template/email/password_new.phtml while it should have been a different template, or the links in this template should be different.

Does anyone else experience this problem? Namely, should I just update the template, or is this a problem in controller which selects the wrong template ?

Comment: Do you have e-mail templates under System > Transactional Emails configured? Maybe the linking there is wrong.

Comment: No, i am not using that functionality. I edit all my templates via file system.